# Парсер avito на python с помощью selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

При запуске скрипта парсит только 6 объявлений, хотя selenium с кнопкой взаимодействует. В чём может быть проблема?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from selenium import webdriver


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def write_csv(data):
    with open('avito-realty.csv', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow((data['title'], data['price'], data['metro'], data['url']))


def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    ads = soup.find('div', class_='recommendations-list js-recommendations-list').find_all('div', class_ = 'recommendations-item')
    driver = webdriver.Edge()
    driver.get('https://www.avito.ru/moskva/nedvizhimost')
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button button-origin button-origin_large button-origin_full-width recommendations-show-more js-recommendations-show-more"]').click()

    # title, price, metro, url
    for ad in ads:
        try:
            title = ad.find('a', class_ = 'description-title-link js-item-link').text
        except:
            title = ''

        try:
            price = ad.find('div', class_ = 'option price').text.strip()
        except:
            price = ''

        try:
            metro = ad.find('div', class_ = 'fader item_gallery-ellipsis').text
        except:
            metro = ''

        try:
            url = 'https://www.avito.ru' + ad.find('a', class_ = 'description-title-link js-item-link').get('href')
        except:
            url = ''

        data = {'title' : title,
                'price' : price,
                'metro' : metro,
                'url' : url}


        write_csv(data)


def main():
    url = 'https://www.avito.ru/moskva/nedvizhimost'
    html = get_html(url)
    get_data(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы свой собственный код точно хорошо посмотрели?

Я вам вот прямо пальцем покажу что не так и почему только 6 объявок))))
И вот в кратце))

Вы реквестом сходили на сайт и получили голый HTML. То есть, эти самые 6 объявок, которые грузятся без ЯваСкрипта. Потом вы эти 6 объявок отдали Супу и положили всё это в переменную `ads`. После этого у вас есть 3 строки с запуском браузера:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://www.avito.ru/moskva/nedvizhimost')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button button-origin button-origin_large button-origin_full-width recommendations-show-more js-recommendations-show-more"]').click()
```

Которые с общим кодом не связаны вообще никак. И вот тут то у вас и случился разрыв вашего шаблона))))
После этих строк вы продолжаете циклом `for` искать объявки в переменной `ads` в которой 6 объявок загруженных без ЯваСкрипта)))) Это и есть ваш итог))

Супер в ктарце - Вы реквестом открываете один сайт, а Селениумом другой, и они никак не взаимодействуют! То есть вы на протяжении всего кода ищите только в том, что загрузил Реквест!

Вам в данной задаче вообще не нужен ни Суп ни реквест)
После:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://www.avito.ru/moskva/nedvizhimost')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button button-origin button-origin_large button-origin_full-width recommendations-show-more js-recommendations-show-more"]').click()
```

использйте

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath()
```

и найденные элементы по атрибутам отдайте в csv

или

```
driver.page_source()
```

отдавайте супу)))))

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source(), 'lxml')
```

Зачем вам здесь реквест я вот как-то вообще не пойму)